# Using async/await not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function and it does async db search operation.

```
var get_all_channels = function {
    return new Promise(()=> {
        db.find({type:'pricing'},{channel_name:1},function(err,docs){
        if(err)
            return err;
        var c = []
        docs.forEachOf(function(ch){
            c.push(ch['channel_name'])
        })
        return c;
    })
    })
}

async function send(){
    return await get_all_channels()
}
function calculate(){
    send().then(res => alert(res))    
}
```

Here, the above function is not working. I don't know why? Please help me fix this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resolve the promise with the results, the array `c`, in `get_all_channels`:

```
var get_all_channels = function {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        db.find({type:'pricing'},{channel_name:1},function(err,docs){
        if(err) {
            reject(err)
            return
        }

        var c = []
        docs.forEachOf(function(ch){
            c.push(ch['channel_name'])
        })

        resolve(c)
    })
    })
}
```

And in `calculate`, you can also use `await` if you want, and, as pointed by @netchkin, you don't need the `async/await` in `send` as long as it just returns the `await`:

```
function send(){
   return get_all_channels()
}

async function calculate(){
   alert(await send())  
}
```

Comment: When you create a promise, you need to pass two callbacks, a `resolve` and a `reject`. You need to call the resolve with the results when everything is ok, and call reject with the error when it goes wrong

Comment: if your async function only returns await, you don't need async await at all. Just pass through the promise. `async function send(){ return await get_all_channels() }` becomes `function send(){ return get_all_channels() }`, which can be deleted

Comment: So,how do you do that? This promise thing is very confusing for me @netchkin

Comment: @bigbounty I have modified my comment, if you have any questions regarding promises, feel free to ask them :)

Comment: Edited my answer with that great tip from @netchkin :)

Comment: How do I reduce the code in the above answer?can I directly use the db operations as a new Promise?

Comment: @bigbounty: you can use directly `get_all_channels` function whereever you need. You just need to take into account the call context - if you call `get_all_channels` from an async function, you should do `const channels = await get_all_channels()`. If you call it from a sync function, then you need to use `.then()` or `catch()` to react on the result of `get_all_channels`

Comment: In the last snippet, `send` is unnecessary.